# XML schema multiple attribute

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I'm trying to create a required elements which has different sub elements. Example XMl file like this:

```
<datamodel>
    <info name="user">
        <userRight>add user</userRight>
    </info>
    <info name="admin">
        <role>manager</role>
    </info>
</datamodel>
```

I currently have the following xml schema.

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="datamodel">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="info" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" >
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="userRight" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="role" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="optional" fixed="user"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="info" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="userRight" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="role" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="optional" fixed="admin"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

However given XML schema will not work with example XML file which I have. How can I modify the schema for validate such a XML?

Comment: So you are trying to change the required nodes under info based on the value in the `name` attribute?

Comment: It's system specifc XMl file and I wan't able to change the XML content. However that content shoul be validate and only way to differentiate it using  name attribute value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could achieve what you want with XML Schema 1.1, with the [Type Alternative](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xml11pt2/) mechanism. It would look something like this:

```
<xs:element name="info" type="xs:anyType">
    <xs:alternative test="@name='user'" type="userRightType"/>
    <xs:alternative test="@name='admin'" type="roleType"/>
</xs:element>
```

Next, find an XML Parser that supports XML Schema 1.1. You did not mention which language you use but I think the latest Xerces2 Java supports it.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use Relax NG instead of XML Schema, it's also supported by Xerces, Saxon and most libraries, and makes it quite easy to specify this sort of thing, e.g.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<grammar 
  xmlns="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"
  xmlns:a="http://relaxng.org/ns/compatibility/annotations/1.0"
  datatypeLibrary="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-datatypes">

  <start>
    <element name="datamodel">
      <oneOrMore>
        <ref name="info" />
      </oneOrMore>
    </element>
  </start>

  <define name="info">
    <element name="info">
      <choice>
        <group>
         <attribute name="name">
           <value>user</value>
         </attribute>
         <oneOrMore>
           <ref name="user-right" />
         </oneOrMore>
        </group>
        <group>
          <attribute name="name">
            <value>admin</value>
          </attribute>
          <oneOrMore>
            <ref name="role" />
          </oneOrMore>
        </group>
      </choice>
    </element>
  </define>

  <define name="role">
    <element name="role">
      <choice>
        <value>admin</value>
        <value>manager</value>
        <value>user</value>
      </choice>
    </element>
  </define>

  <define name="user-right">
    <element name="userRight">
      <choice>
        <value>add user</value>
        <value>delete user</value>
        <value>edit user</value>
      </choice>
    </element>
  </define>
</grammar>
```

Each `group` specifies a `name` attribute with a specific value and one or more elements of a particular type, and those types themselves are constrained to specific values.

Personally I find Relax NG much more natural than XML Schema, and it does allow you to specify rules that you can't using XSD. The tutorial is about all you need as a reference, it really is quite straightforward :)

http://relaxng.org/tutorial-20011203.html